# What exactly is Trunks' new transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Some people say it is a False Super Saiyan God, other people say it is a Super Saiyan God 2, while another group of people say it is something different. Is there any official info on what it is exactly?

Comment: Do you mean in the manga or the anime?  They differ a bit, though I don't think either really specifies.

Comment: As far as I remember, they havent reached to the new transformation in the manga. Isnt the last manga chapter 17? It ends with Goku visiting Zeno sama which happens before Trunks's new transformation

Comment: Trunks has displayed what might be a new transformation in the manga.  He matched SSJ3 Goku while staying at a SSJ2 level soon after he returned from the future.  Nothing beyond that, as you say.

Comment: I think that just is a strong SSJ2. Remember, Vegita in SSJ2 is said to surpass Goku SSJ3 in the moment he got mad because Beerus slapped Bulma, so it's possible for a saiyan in SSJ2 to be as strong or stronger than a saiyan in SSJ3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it finally has an official name for the transformation. It is called 超サイヤ人怒り *(Sūpā Saiya-jin Ikari)* which means *[Super Saiyan Rage](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Rage)* or *Super Saiyan Anger*. The form makes its first appearance in [Dragon Ball Z: Dokkan Battle](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Dokkan_Battle) and properly named in [Super Dragon Ball Heroes](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Heroes).

**Dragon Ball Z: Dokkan Battle**

[image]

**Super Dragon Ball Heroes**

[image]

Comment: any info about how powerful it is?

Comment: @Pablo The overall power is stated in the Super Saiyan Rage wikia page. Though, you can learn more about DBS power scaling on YouTube.

Answer (score 5):

No as of today 11/4/2016 there is no name or real explanation as to what it is or how it works. I suspect it will be revealed towards the end of the current arc.

Answer (score 5):

As Kaz Rodgers correctly points outs, there are no in-universe explanation yet. However, we can try and make some assumptions.

To understand Trunks' transformation, we have to go back and revisit the time when Vegeta became Super Saiyan Blue (SSB). At first, it is explained that the only way a Saiyan can get God Ki is by performing the ritual with 5 Super Saiyans they did at the beginning of the new series. So how did Vegeta do it? His first transformation into SSB happens after he has trained with Whis and Beerus for 6 months. Therefore, it is possible that some of Whis and Beerus' God ki has rub off on Vegeta after spending so much time with them.

Now back to Trunks. With the same reasoning, we can assume that some of Vegeta's and Son Goku's God ki diffused into Trunks. However, unlike Whis and Beerus, they are not Gods and therefore Trunks was only able to get some of God ki but clearly not enough to power up to SSB directly.

Comment: Personally I think he just learned to use some grade of god ki just by watching Vegeta in his fight with him. Just as he learned Mafuba by watching, and also probably Galick-ho and the spirit bomb (which he could have learned if the events of the movie Super Android 13 happened to some extent). Since many of the events of the movies Battle of Gods and Fukkatsu no F actually happened later in the series, it's possible